# How can I restrict FTP and SMB access to computers on the internal network

Tags: linux, ftp, raspberry-pi, smb

I have Installed samba  and tried adding this line config file for samba

```
Listen=yes
```

Listen_address= 127.0.0.1
I have also put this in vsftpd.cnf
It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The IP addresses 127.x.x.x are always restricted to the local host only, so when other computers try that they connect only to themselves.  Assuming you have Linux on a Raspberry Pi, see what other IP addresses it has that connect with the outside world like this:

```
/sbin/ifconfig
```

and then use one of those addresses instead.  Also try to ping the address from your other computers - if that doesn't work then ftp has little chance of working either.

The [vsftpd.conf documentation](http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html) suggests that the default is to listen on all local addresses.  You could try that by commenting out the listen_address line with a # at the start of the line, and then restart the vsftpd server process.

Do not confuse samba and vsftp.  They are two separate server processes that use different protocols, port numbers and configuration files.

Beware of case sensitive options, the wrong case will not work.  You wrote Listen but probably meant listen ;-)

Comment: But will this restrict both smb and ftp to internal network only? In smb.conf I have added this line [global]
  hosts allow = 127.0.0.1 192.168.1.0/24 which I think works, but What FTP, how do I restrict the usage to internal networks only

Comment: I have searched the linked vsftpd documentation for "restrict", "limit", "network" and "subnet", and it appears that vsftpd does not support such a restriction.  On the other hand, 192.168.x.x is invariably a private subnet behind a NAT firewall anyway.  Your FTP service is therefore not accessible from other networks unless you deliberately add some NAT port forwarding.

Comment: Does NAT firewall includes allowing access to user external IP address?

Comment: Standard NAT firewall denies access to all external IP addresses.

Comment: Well I have allowed the access, as I use my raspberry pi through putty when I am not at home

Comment: Now I need to restrict the access of FTP and SAMBA to internal network for the network drive

Comment: That will work safely if you enable NAT port forwarding only for putty (default SSH port 22) and do not enable port forwarding for any other ports.

Comment: I have to enable port forwarding on post 80 and 443 as I am using SSL certificate too.

Comment: That is also fine because those ports connect to your web server, not your FTP or Samba servers.  By using NAT forwarding of custom ports I SSH from anywhere into two, sometimes three Raspberry Pis at home.  They're great!

Comment: But my question was what do I need to do in order to block external access

Comment: Do these settings work  in smb.conf`[global]
  hosts allow = 127.0.0.1 192.168.1.0/24
in vsftpd.conf
tcp_wrappers=YES
in host allow
vsftpd: 192.168.1.
in host.deny
vsftpd: ALL
`

Comment: You already did what you needed to do to block external access when you put a NAT router between your LAN and the Internet.  It's a one way street allowing only outward connections except for the ports 22 80 and 443 that you allowed.  Just try it from elsewhere, even with everything you know about your LAN you will never connect inward to Samba or FTP from other networks.  It's safe.  Leave those other settings the way they were, changing them is not useful in your particular situation.

Comment: It did not work. So just to clarify, I have port forwarding allowed for port 443, 80, 22. And I have added these settings, I tried to access FTP from external network it did not work

Comment: StackOverflow suggests moving this extended discussion to a chat room but you need a reputation of 20 to use that.  I suggest posting a new question instead with more detail about what currently works and what does not.